# How to do multi-face tracking with ARKit 3?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I am trying to make an application that supports multi-face tracking. The project has multiple buttons to change face assets. For very first time app detects multiple faces but when I click on the buttons to change the asset it does not work for both faces but only works with a new face. I am confused about what's wrong in my code?

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    guard ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else { return }
    let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedFaces = 2
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

func setAsset(strItem:String)
{
    let documentsUrl:URL =  (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL?)!
    let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(strItem)")
    referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(url: destinationFileUrl)!
    referenceNode.load()
    let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)!
    faceGeometry.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = []
    occlusionNode = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
    occlusionNode.renderingOrder = -1
    referenceNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.0014, 0.0014, 0.0014)
    referenceNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0.04, 0.07)
    contentNode!.addChildNode(occlusionNode)
    contentNode!.addChildNode(referenceNode)
}


extension ViewController : ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        print(anchors.count)
        for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {
            
            let faceAnchor = anchor as! ARFaceAnchor
            
            print("Session didAdd", faceAnchor.identifier)
        }
    }
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        
        for anchor in anchors where anchor is ARFaceAnchor {
            
            let faceAnchor = anchor as! ARFaceAnchor
            
            print("Session didUpdate", faceAnchor.identifier)
            
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController : ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor else { return }
        currentFaceAnchor = faceAnchor
        self.setAsset(strItem:"dummy1.scn" )
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        guard let sceneView = renderer as? ARSCNView,
            anchor is ARFaceAnchor else { return nil }
        let faceGeometry = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)!
        faceGeometry.firstMaterial!.colorBufferWriteMask = []
        occlusionNode = SCNNode(geometry: faceGeometry)
        occlusionNode.renderingOrder = -1
        contentNode = SCNNode()
        return contentNode
    }
    
}
```